# Продление времени жизни временного объекта в присваивании

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, оператор-присваивания

```
#include <iostream>

int destructions;
struct A { ~A() noexcept { ++destructions; } };

int main() {
  {
    const A& a = A{} = A{};
    std::cout << "Destructions in scope:     " << destructions << '\n';
    destructions = 0;
  }
  std::cout << "Destructions out of scope: " << destructions << '\n';
}
```

Почему данный код [возвращает разные результаты](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGISQBspK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgAJykAA6oCoRODB7evv5BaRmOAmER0SxxCcl2mA5ZQgRMxAQ5Pn6Btpj2xQwNTQSlUbHxSbaNza15HQrjA%2BFDFSOJAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDM4cjeWADUJrtuTjPEmKxn2CYaAIIPj%2BEEx1hXXnUCCmdWTy%2BDmOj1OAHYLMcAH6PCDLY4MVCYVRbFLvEwQ06WayfAjEb49P67SEYgAi4NJ/xeLzexxYTHCcPBANBzJexw5xzQDBmIPMAWOTFOu3JzwhZOFooxVjBlOJ7M5M3QIBQ63R5zObixZlJmCBhOO4WOCjQKXYnI55jMwrcmo%2BerxBKyChtdrAOwArG4GO6qU8Lbj8T8eZLjho/ayyQqlSq0F51bbztrdfrncc1emqMbTeara6k4Gnb981rfV6fTt5U8yRxVrROB7eH4OFpSKhOLbsZZjetNpgsbseKQCJpa6sANb%2BRIAOkkc40AA4uBpEguwR6wbsgvWOJIm6O25xeAoQBph6PVnBYDBECBkbV4yRyJQmsAFMpDF0hAhUAB3ZtDmgLApHQTA9B%2BES0N%2Bf4AbwQEgfQCTAFwZhmKQ8F0PEADy8bQf%2BnBDveyCPMQb5HsEqi1A0%2BDNrw/CCCIYjsFIMiCIoKjqC2Oh6AYRgoNY1j6HgMQnpAqyoGizqcAAtEqZykqYXYWGYrYKL2Wx6Eq4QQV%2BP74dwvB4pg2xDr%2BxBMCkBG1voDb7lxh4cNglHII%2BxDHKoC4BNJASSMcwDIMgxwodO1oQJ2ViWKQxy4IQJADlwyyGReqwIDcWAJHCNm7rwLAgLsuzTokGiBIkuylQEGgelwVUeqQzatu2HDHqe55cZeN4QEgRGuc%2BECvu%2Bn5QXpsHoagwGgeBg14SNGGISgvHAAA%2Bo6DDjqN42IThwjDVZFG1CRZFNXtyDUeE5H0cIojiCxF3sWoB66GhC38UpQkifA4mSb8MlySKikRcpqnqcxYw0TpQ0wbtRkmbwZkWVZda2XVB6NU5D5EG5HleT5XILccEAreO8JhQJkXRfgGPxYlrVaMsKVpSMmU7nupC5YOs5gmYYJcFwARgpViQBLs0j1bwjXNWeI5taQV63t1GO9f14PTbts1gVkys7QZ60ISMABuyApCki161wiSLQYBAOotqg%2BTrmHEFtKva0RB0nkdRGnbRrGXUxEjSLdSj3fZui7PohjGKTNi0MJomZRJhKcAA9DG/3WCpx7A5pBBg1NWtDtDu1w5ZBmIxwjbI/ZqPOa57k4ywCgG8cpszpbDr4%2BFgnk7Fbl7AlSVtfTTDpZQZcs2zkjTgEqEeokkhlflHpmFItWiw5Es02OpCTh6GjTh6B%2BJFwC5FShkhmAEtU7rsdkNeRUu02XZi32L9/JaQevxBkziSEAA%3D) на GCC, Clang и MSVC? Кто из них прав в соответствии со стандартом?

Comment: Вероятнее всего дело не в стандарте, а в работе оптимизаторов. gcc увидел что новый объект присваивается новому объекту (у которого нет данных и нет конструктора - значит они одинаковые) и просто сконструировал 1 объект. Поэтому получился 1 вызов деструктора при выходе из  scope. clang честно создал 2 объекта и потом вызвал деструкторы. А вот результаты msvc трудно объяснить.

Comment: @DmitryK в сумме же все компиляторы вызвали 2 деструктора, а значит и создалось 2 объекта везде. Разница во времени их уничтожения. Кстати, в примере уровень оптимизации не указан, а значит т.н. оптимизатор не применятся (хотя могут применяться "оптимизации" более ранние)

Comment: О, сошлось! Если последовательно идти, то деструкторы должны вызываться  при выходе из scope.  Т.е. у вас деструктор вызывается после присваивания `desctructions = 0;` И тогда msvc отработал логично, gcc скорее всего один объект разрушил сразу после присваивания (т.к. он временный), а второй при выходе из scope. А  clang видимо сразу разрушил объекты, т.к. ни они ни ссылка нигде больше не используются.

Comment: `clang` - лажанул в стандарте. Он не имеет право уничтожить временный объект `const A& a`, так как у объекта продлевается время жизни из-за ссылки, а деструктор имеет право вызываться **только** после окончания времени жизни объекта. `gcc` - делает чётко по правилам, а `msvc` - не нарушил правил по порядку удаления и имеет право потянуть.

Comment: @AlexGlebe был бы признателен за ответ со ссылками на пункты стандарта, подтверждающие ваши слова

Comment: @AlexGlebe, достойно ответа

Comment: @Mister_Jesus не получается ответить, так как у меня при проверки **все** компиляторы моментально удаляют два объекта и падают. https://godbolt.org/z/eosaf8nvM при вызове `fun(a);`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, если убрать volatile, то gcc компилирует ...

Comment: @Mister_Jesus **volatile** удаляет оптимизацию, а оптимизация мешает деструктору менять указатель на нулевой. А нулевой указатель мне нужен как индикатор того, что объект уже удалён.

Comment: Так там ручной `nullptr`, не должно быть по сути важно уже. В любом случае какая-то фигня

Answer (score 6):

Для начала определим какие объекты называются временными.
Категория объектов `A{}` называется *r-value* если программа сама создала объект и знает время его жизни. Прикрепление *r-value* объекта к переменной с приставкой `&&` или `const &` продлевает это время в блоке, где эта ссылка находится.

Примеры :

```
A && a = A{};
A const & a = A{};
A fun(){
  ..
}
..
A && y = fun();
A const & z = fun();
```

Но другие временные объекты, такие как

```
A && funt(){
  ..
}
..
A && x = std::move(A{});
A && y = funt ();
A const & z = (A{} = A{}) ;
```

и присваиваются к таким-же типам `A &&` или `A const &` называются по-другому : `x-value` *(an “eXpiring” value)* и имеют очень короткое время жизни. Компилятор не обязан продлевать время жизни таких ссылок, так как этот объект был создан другими участками кода.

То-есть работа с переменными `x`,`y`,`z` прикреплённые к висячим ссылкам к `x-value` объектам имеют неопределённое поведение. Например функция `funt` могла возвращать ссылку на статический объект или на временный. И временный объект уже может быть удалён.

В вашем примере оператор присваивания `A{} = A{}`  возвращает ссылку на объект `x-value` и прикрепление к ссылке на переменную не увеличивает время жизни объекта и ваша ссылка называется висячей. Время жизни данного объекта уже истекло.

Посмотрим стандарт про вызов деструктора :

> 11.4.7  **Destructors**  [class.dtor]
>
> 15 A destructor is invoked implicitly (15.3)
>
> — for a constructed object with automatic storage duration (6.7.5.4)
> when the block in which an object is created exits (8.8), (15.4)
> — for a constructed temporary object when its lifetime ends (7.3.5, 6.7.7).

И он говорит, во что временном объекте должен быть вызван деструктор когда заканчивается его время жизни.

То-есть самый правильный компилятор - это **clang**, который удаляет оба временных объекта сразу.

Comment: *А стандарт разрешает приложениям НЕ вызывать деструктор ИМЕННО в области блока жизни переменной для оптимизации* — но ведь это не следует из приведённого пункта стандарта. В стандарте говорится, что надо вызывать деструктор в конце блока, если он имеет побочные эффекты, а не опускать его вызов либо вызывать его раньше конца блока.

Comment: `shall not destroy` - переводится как НЕ должен. @tocic

Comment: *shall not destroy it before the end of its block* — не должен уничтожать до конца блока. Вы же говорите, что можно уничтожать и не в этом блоке, чего нет в этом пункте.

Comment: Все созданные объекты должны быть удалены. Это как библия. @tocic Я стандарт привёл. Перевод автоматический. Как по-вашему правильнее перевести - предложите.

Comment: Моя претензия не к переводу пункта стандарта, и я не утверждаю, что объекты могут быть не удалены. Моя претензия в том, что вы утверждаете, что можно вызвать деструктор не в том же блоке, где объявлена ссылка в вопросе. В качестве доказательства этого утверждения вы приводите пункт стандарта, где говорится, что при наличии побочных эффектов в деструкторе реализация не должна его оптимизировать. Там не говорится про то, что можно вызывать деструктор позже блока с объявлением. Так что для доказательства вашего утверждения надо привести другой пункт.

Comment: Ещё раз почитал стандарт, короче это правило запрещает удалять рано объекты с деструктором с побочным эффектом. А этот пример как раз с таким. Насчёт того,что позже - не говорится. И если можно позже, то единственное правило для деструкторов осталось - это выполнять их в обратном порядке от создания и всё. Я правильно понял? @tocic

Comment: _Категория объектов A{} называется r-value_ r-value — это единица измерения теплопроводности туристических ковриков и спальников. В C++ — rvalue. И rvalue это классификация выражений, а не объектов.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вместо общего подсчета вызовов деструктора сделать лог конструкторов и деструкторов. Результат может удивить. Например у меня в онлайн-компиляторе  создалось 3 объекта, а не 2.

```
#include <iostream>

int desctructions = 0;
unsigned int count = 0;

struct A 
{   
    unsigned int num;
    A() noexcept {  
        num = count++; 
        std::cout << "Construct " << num << " object\n";
    }
    ~A() noexcept { 
        ++desctructions; 
        std::cout << "Destruct " << num << " object\n";
    } 
};

int main() 
{
  {
    A& a = A{} = A{};
    a.num += 10;
    std::cout << "Destructions in scope1:    " << desctructions << '\n';
    desctructions = 0;
    std::cout << "Destructions in scope2:    " << desctructions << '\n';
  }
  std::cout << "Destructions out of scope: " << desctructions << '\n';
}
```

Вот теперь видно, когда конструируются и разрушаются объекты.

Comment: Ссылка ведёт на мой пример. Если вставить ваш код, то вижу везде только 2 строки с `"Construct"`

Comment: У gcc и clang 2 строки `Construct` и 2 строки `Destruct 0 object` сразу, до `desctructions = 0;`. А в msvc сначала 2 строки `Construct`, потом присваивание, потом 2 строки `Destruct`.

Answer (score 1):

`clang` прав, в соответствии со стандартом два деструктора должны быть вызваны в конце объявления ссылки до первой печати.

---

Для начала заметим, что сначала выполняется `A{} = A{}`, а потом результат этого выражения присваивается ссылке. Причём сначала выполняется `A{}` в правой части присваивания, после — в левой, после — само присваивание.

[[expr.ass]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.ass#1):

> The assignment operator (`=`) and the compound assignment operators
> all group right-to-left. ... In all cases, the assignment is sequenced
> after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before
> the value computation of the assignment expression. The right operand
> is sequenced before the left operand. ...

Выражение `A{} = A{}` эквивалентно `A{}.operator=(A{})`.

[[over.binary]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.binary#general-1):

> ... For **an expression `x @ y`** with subexpressions `x` and `y`, the operator
> function is selected by overload resolution
> ([[over.match.oper]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.match.oper)).
> **If a member function is selected**, the expression **is interpreted as**
>
> **`x . operator @ ( y )`**
>
> Otherwise, if a non-member function is selected, the expression is
> interpreted as
>
> `operator @ ( x , y )`

Т.к. у нашего класса нет явного объявления оператора присваивания, он будет объявлен неявно в виде `A& A::operator=(const A&)`. Что интересно, перемещающий оператор присваивания не будет объявлен из-за наличия пользовательского деструктора, а объявление копирующего оператора присваивания в этом случае является *deprecated* поведением.

[[class.copy.assign]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.copy.assign#2):

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment
> operator, one is declared *implicitly*. If the class definition
> declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the
> implicitly declared copy assignment operator is defined as deleted;
> otherwise, it is defined as defaulted
> ([[dcl.fct.def]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.fct.def)).
> The latter case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy
> constructor or a user-declared destructor
> ([[depr.impldec]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/depr.impldec)).
> The implicitly-declared copy assignment operator for a class `X` will
> have the form
>
> `X& X::operator=(const X&)`
>
> if
>
> - each direct base class `B` of `X` has a copy assignment operator whose parameter is of type `const B&`, `const volatile B&`, or `B`,
>   and
> - for all the non-static data members of `X` that are of a class type `M` (or array thereof), each such class type has a copy assignment
>   operator whose parameter is of type `const M&`, `const volatile M&`,
>   or `M`.
>
> ...

[[class.copy.assign]/4.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.copy.assign#4.4):

> If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move
> assignment operator, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if
> and only if
>
> - ...
> - `X` does not have a user-declared destructor.

Вспомним, что оба выражения `A{}` являются *prvalue*.

[[expr.type.conv]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.type.conv):

> **A *simple-type-specifier* or *typename-specifier* followed** by a
> parenthesized optional *expression-list* or **by a *braced-init-list*
> (the initializer)** constructs a value of the specified type given the
> initializer. ...
>
> If the initializer is a parenthesized single expression, the type
> conversion expression is equivalent to the corresponding *cast
> expression*. Otherwise, if the type is *cv* `void` and the initializer
> is `()` or `{}` (after pack expansion, if any), the expression is a
> prvalue of the specified type that performs no initialization.
> Otherwise, **the expression is a prvalue** of the specified type whose
> result object is *direct-initialized* with the initializer. ...

Теперь понятно, что правое выражение `A{}` создаёт временный объект, т.к. необходимо выполнить *binding* ссылки `const A&` к *prvalue* `A{}`.

[[class.temporary]/2.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.temporary#2.1):

> ... Temporary objects are materialized:
>
> - when binding a reference to a prvalue ([[dcl.init.ref]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.init.ref),
>   [[expr.type.conv]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.type.conv),
>   [[expr.dynamic.cast]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.dynamic.cast),
>   [[expr.static.cast]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.static.cast),
>   [[expr.const.cast]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.const.cast),
>   [[expr.cast]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.cast)),
> - ...

Левое выражение `A{}` также создаёт временный объект, т.к. необходимо выполнить доступ к функции-члену в `A{}.operator=()`.

[[class.temporary]/2.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.temporary#2.2):

> ... Temporary objects are materialized:
>
> - ...
> - when performing member access on a class prvalue ([[expr.ref]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.ref),
>   [[expr.mptr.oper]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.mptr.oper)),
> - ...

Для этих двух временных объектов обязаны быть вызваны 2 деструктора, т.к. они нетривиальны.

[[class.temporary]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.temporary#4):

> When an implementation introduces a temporary object of a class that
> has a non-trivial constructor
> ([[class.default.ctor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.default.ctor),
> [[class.copy.ctor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.copy.ctor)),
> it shall ensure that a constructor is called for the temporary object.
> Similarly, **the destructor shall be called for a temporary with a
> non-trivial destructor**
> ([[class.dtor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.dtor)).
> ...

[[class.dtor]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.dtor#8):

> **A destructor is trivial if it is not user-provided** and if:
>
> - ...

Они должны быть вызваны в конце выражения, в котором содержатся (в вопросе это выражение до первой печати), за исключением трёх ситуаций.

[[class.temporary]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.temporary#4):

> ... Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the
> full-expression
> ([[intro.execution]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/intro.execution))
> that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. ...

[[class.temporary]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.temporary#5):

> There are three contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a
> different point than the end of the full-expression. ...

Из указанных в стандарте трёх ситуаций подозрительна только ситуация с продлением времени жизни временного объекта в случае *binding* ссылки `const A& a` к результату присваивания `A{} = A{}` (правый временный объект уже связан со ссылкой из оператора присваивания).

[[class.temporary]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.temporary#6):

> The third context is when a reference is bound to a temporary object.
> ...

Однако ни один из случаев, когда такой *binding* может происходить, не подходит в нашей ситуации. Это неочевидно только в первом из 12 случаев (не буду приводить их [все](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.temporary#6) для краткости).

[[class.temporary]/6.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.temporary#6.1):

> ... The temporary object to which the reference is bound or the
> temporary object that is the complete object of a subobject to which
> the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference if
> the glvalue to which the reference is bound was obtained through one
> of the following:
>
> - a temporary materialization conversion ([[conv.rval]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/conv.rval)),
> - ...

Но *temporary materialization conversion* также не срабатывает, потому что это преобразование из *prvalue* в *xvalue*, а результат сгенерированного оператора присваивания у нас не является *prvalue* (ранее было указано объявление `A& A::operator=(const A&)`).

[[conv.rval]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/conv.rval#1):

> A prvalue of type T can be converted to an xvalue of type T. This
> conversion initializes a temporary object
> ([[class.temporary]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.temporary))
> of type T from the prvalue by evaluating the prvalue with the
> temporary object as its result object, and produces an xvalue denoting
> the temporary object. ...

---

Также можно рассмотреть [следующий пример](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:24,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:24,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:24,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:24,startLineNumber:9),source:%27struct+A+%7B+bool+x%3B+%7D%3B%0A%0Aconsteval+bool+foo()+%7B%0A++const+A%26+a+%3D+A%7B%7D+%3D+A%7B%7D%3B%0A++return+a.x%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++static_assert(foo())%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:38.39110529758012,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1500,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27),(h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:61.60889470241988,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:1,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4):

```
struct A { bool x; };

consteval bool foo() {
  const A& a = A{} = A{};
  return a.x;
}

int main() {
  static_assert(foo());
}
```

> note: read of object outside its lifetime is not allowed in a constant
> expression
>
> return a.x;

То есть временные объекты уже уничтожены после объявления.

Добавление пользовательского оператора присваивания приводит к [согласию всех компиляторов с `clang`](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAA7KQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfFJdpgOmUIETMQE2T5%2BgVU1AnUNBMWRMXGJtvWNzbltwz1hfWUDCQCUtqhexMjsHOb%2BYcjeWADUJv5uTgoExJisB9gmGgCC1zdhBLtYJ8ReHQwKB1a3r%2B9PN32CR%2BgN2YLuZgAbLtUMk4kwiMQDgARCBoT4A8yQuZAiy7M4EZYMXYAKgICDwX38eJMCWR33uYLBAD8bhAcQxUJhVKtkk9aTTLNYXqd/pkqTS6fdafTqdLbo9diwmGF2bjGerbkzduiTrsIdCmPt/Mj9QKZcbTXdgTKGVqmSd0CAUEt%2BYcDm59mYzMjMH8PgpdmFdgo0HCQNqvWZjW4Pc8/aKAzG42B1gBWNwMVN20FgkVvJMo3YaHNg232x3OtBeN2xw5R33%2BxwCQOumFUENh9hR5P1/Nilu9z3ZjNZ9Zy24yjgLWicNO8PwcLSkVCcWNCywhpYrTBe/w8UgETTThYAaxAkgAnAA6SR3jQADi4GkvD4SaYS/kh%2Bk4kgXx5XTheAUEANEPY8FjgWAYEQEBuWqGsSHISgGmABRlEMTBaCEBBUAAd0XA80BYZI6ARTIMPCbDcIIzgiNQEi6AGYAuG9UhiNI%2BhiAAeRrHD8MI3h4OQG5iDQoCglUao6nwRdeH4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdQlx0PQDCMFBrGsfQ8GiEDIAWWFm0%2BTgAFpHRRUwNwsMxlwUbdVj0R0wkorD%2BNo7heFOTA1gPPDiCYZI6OnH8OHnUhF2XVcOGwKTkEQ4hdlUB9IRsyFJF2YBkGQXZWOvaMIHXKxLFIXZcEIEg9y4OZAoghYEHOLB4nZGK/1IFgAn8a9Lw0SRIUvfxxshDQ0y4Ga03igCkuA0DwO0yCYIgJBhPS5CIFQ9DMOogSovYhjOPIgQfKO/z6MYriUD0li0w0MCOKYni%2BJowTJOqUTxI4ITUpksIJIU4RRHEVSwY0tQAN0Mx9EMYxDOq2gTLM7rLPFWz7JNRyqucjRdjsgh0DR6IUXJ/HrGA9yVKGWSrr876gpC3gwoiqKZznf9tMA5LUvSzLsty/LtiRkq02vDRpd2CqUZsWr8ERRrmtWrQ5jajqBm62cOF6/r91vBIzASLguEhBJpsvSF/GkBLeCW2wVqPNbSCg2DtsRXb9qZr6TregwrL946AtOu6BgAN2QZJkgAfUjrhLzj/wzDj1Q8vDzi4l44R/bD4S/pAgGfuQYG5LU8HlIkaRoaUWG%2Bd0QJHoMpzjNM%2BALL5bGOAAekranLBc2nlg8rgGe8w7mZO1mTo5yKAu52LecSzgUoQlWM/ylgFGj3ZE5vVO5cqoylfqjKNialq1q1phOsoJeDYCSRr0hb000vSQJv8fw0zMKR5oO35stMCrsNZnhAM9a8aYYGXi4A%2BYarFJBQnmnrfwK9HYSTASeGKZgMHAPVjgyOcR0jOEkEAA%3D).