# Константная ссылка на r-value

Tags: c++

Константная ссылка на r-value

Что это значит?

```
const int& perf = 35;

std::cout << perf;
```

Comment: *"Что это значит?"* В каком смысле?

Comment: А что конкретно непонятно? PS: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/731506/178988

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1450260/312941

Answer (score 5):

Константная **l-value** ссылка может быть привязана и к **r-value** объекту *(не путать с **r-value** ссылкой)*. И время жизни данного объекта увеличивается до конца области действия переменной.

Это значит, что **r-value** объект **35** привязывается к константной **l-value** ссылке **perf**.